# Integrate reCAPTCHA Enterprise with Android apps and Python as Backend

Tags: python, django, recaptcha

I want to Integrate reCAPTCHA Enterprise on Front-end (Android) and with Back-end Python on Login. I have implemented on Android and perfectly generating reCAPTCHA `response`.

**Problem**

I send reCAPTCHA generated `response` to Back-end (Django) in `HTTP/POST` API call to verify on Back-end. On Back-end I call `'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'` and binded the reCAPTCHA `response` with `GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY` to verify the user generated reCAPCHA. But I get message [`invalid-input-response`] reCAPTCHA in response of `'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'`